# How to use line break textfield?

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I am Create a message application on ios.using textfield to enter message by user.then fire event keyboard enter should start from second line.

please give me a property of line break in textfield.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a multi line text box use a textview :)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html

Make good use of the Dev centre, can find most things in there :]

Answer (score 1):

Whenever implement line break then use this:

```
 NSString *strText =  yourTextField.text;
[strText stringByAppendingString:@"\n"]; //just append string with '\n'
yourTextField.text = strText //changed value with line break
```

It is better to use UITextView as to display more text